# Is My Guppy Sick?

Tags: health, aquarium, fish, freshwater, guppies

My adult guppy has been acting strange in my opinion. He has been inactive unlike the other guppies and platy fish in the tank. I’ve noticed that he has been swimming in place at the top of the tank. I saw him like this in the morning and I just got back from school and he is still there.   This is not like his personality. He would usually swim with the other guppies and chase them not in an aggressive way. (UPDATE) okay so I just fed the whole tank and the guppy did not really bother to eat.  He did see the food, but did not eat.

Questions:

1. Is he sick?
2. Does he look bloated?
3. If he is sick, what illness is it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Pets, I'm not sure but the guppy's fins look a bit wrinkled and a bit off-tune, mostly the tail fin which also looks like it's a bit torn, has it always been looking like that? Besides the fins, I don't see anything of a concern.

Comment: And for me the guppy does not look bloated.

Comment: He has been picked on by the other guppies when I first got them. That has caused the fins to be a bit torn. Later, the fighting stopped and his fins did not seem to heal. I am not sure why it did not heal because I have had fish in this tank with torn fins from plastic plants and their fins have healed in less than a week.

Comment: Bad water parameters could slow down or completely stop wound healing. Do you have water testing kits, could you please post readings of ammonia, nitrites, nitrates and pH? Thanks.

Comment: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/8053/aquarium-size-and-startup-recommendations-for-two-guppies here you can read about guppies and water quality